# Ajax POST request does not work

Tags: javascript, ajax

I don't know what I am doing wrong, but all looks good. I am working on `localhost` and I am having trouble trying to load a file.

This is my code. I am working in NetBeans and console is clear without any errors.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "demo_post.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>AJAX</h2>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Request data</button>
<div id="myDiv"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

When I execute this code, I get no results.

Comment: And why are you not using the JQuery's .ajax feature?

Comment: `console.log(xmlhttp)`

Comment: Tagged "jquery" and uses plain javascript. #likeaboss

Comment: Show us what's inside demo_post.php...

Comment: [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners). Set breakpoints, see what part of the code is executed.

Comment: jQuery isn't always the answer, but when it comes to ajax, jQuery **is** almost always the answer. Your entire function rewritten using jQuery: `$.post('demo_post.php').done(function(result) { $('#myDiv').html(result); });`.

Comment: What are u talking guys. Example is 100% good and that example is from W3 school. http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In between your .open() and .send() invocations, set your request header like so:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "demo_post.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send();
```

At least, that's how you'd do it if you didn't want to use jQuery.

Comment: Thanks setRequestHeader be problem. I fix

Answer (score 0):

As some of the comments suggest - you need to look in the error console of the Browser. NOT NETBEANS. Also, understand how to set breakpoints in JS, etc.

Below is an example of what you are trying to achieve using jQuery which is much simple than using pure Javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

   // jQuery allows you to use selectors rather than onClick, etc
   // So when anything with a class called "loadData" is clicked this function will run       
   $(".loadData").click(function (event) {

       $.ajax({
          url: 'demo_post.php',  // The URL that your making the request to
          type: 'POST', // Type - GET or POST
          dataType: 'html', // DataType - can be html, json or jsonp
          cache: false, // true or false - whether you want data to be cached
          data: 'foo=bar', // Any data that your submitting with the request.
          error: function (error_response) {

             // An error has occured so empty your #myDiv and put the error in there.
             $("#myDiv").empty().append(error_response.status);

          },
          success: function (response) {

             // Everything has worked - empty #myDiv and put the replace with response
             $("#myDiv").empty().append(response);

          }
       });

   });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>AJAX</h2>
<button type="button" class="loadData">Request data</button>
<div id="myDiv"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

You can find more information on jQuery here: http://api.jquery.com and more specifically on jQuery's AJAX functions here - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

i found that your code is actually designed for GET method.And in this case is not important to use POST instead of get.(because no parameter is passed and also its not a form..) and also agrees to @Jackson

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <!--you can use online js file but in here i download the js file from       code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js and kept it in localhost same folder -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function loadXMLDoc()
  {
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
  document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
 }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","demo_post.php",true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h2>AJAX</h2>
 <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Request data</button>
 <div id="myDiv"></div>

 </body>
 </html>
```